# Get target of .each function within a $.proxy function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using RequireJS to structure my JS which is why I'm using a $.proxy function. What I'm trying to do within the .each function is give each carousel on the page a unique data attribute. In order to do this I have to be able to target each carousel, but $(this) in this context doesn't target each carousel. I've tried using currentTarget but I think this only works on click events?

Below is the specific snippet which needs fixing.

```
        getCarousels: function() {
            $carousel.each($.proxy(function(index) {
                $owl = (index.currentTarget);
                $owl.attr('data-number', index);
                this.initCarousel();
            },this));
        },
```

And here is the full file.

```
define(['owlcarousel'], function() {

    var $ = jQuery,
        $carousel = $('.carousel'),
        $data = $('.carousel-data');

        function updateResult(pos, value, carouselNumber) {
            $(carouselNumber).find(pos).text(value);
        }

        function afterAction(el) {
            var owl = el.data('owlCarousel'),
                actualValue = this.owl.currentItem + 1,
                carouselNumber =  el.attr('data-number');

                console.log(carouselNumber);

            updateResult('.carousel-current', actualValue, carouselNumber);
            updateResult('.carousel-items', this.owl.owlItems.length, carouselNumber);
        }

    return {

        init: function() {
            if($carousel.length >= 1) {
                this.setUp();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },

        setUp: function() {
            this.getCarousels();
        },

        getCarousels: function() {
            $carousel.each($.proxy(function(index) {
                $owl = (index.currentTarget);
                $owl.attr('data-number', index);
                this.initCarousel();
            },this));
        },

        initCarousel: function() {
            $carousel.owlCarousel({
                singleItem: true,
                autoPlay: true,
                slideSpeed: 400,
                paginationSpeed: 800,
                lazyLoad: true,
                afterAction: afterAction
            }); 
        }

    };

});
```

Comment: Just use the second argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.each` receive 2 parameters which is the index and the value. Usualy the value is the same as `this`, but well, you overrided it. Get that second parameter! :

```
$carousel.each($.proxy(function(index, el) {
            $owl = $(el);
            $owl.attr('data-number', index);
            this.initCarousel();
        },this));
```

But why not simply not use proxy?

```
var that = this
$carousel.each(function(index) {
            $owl = $(this);
            $owl.attr('data-number', index);
            that.initCarousel();
        });
```